# Logging compression using jboss 7.1

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss7.x

I'm developing an application with JBoss 7.1 where I'm using a periodic-rotating-file-handler tag for creating a history files of logs. What I want to do is compress the files in some format like .gz

I tried to to this:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MY_LOG">
    <filter>
        <all>
            <match pattern="TEXT"/>
        </all>
    </filter>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value="_yyyy-MM-dd.gz"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

but I got this error:

Illegal pattern character 'g'

any idea how to compress with jboss 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

The suffix expects only a pattern that can be parsed by [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). There is no ability to compress the rolled log file from the handler itself.

Comment: FWIW, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Periodic_Log_Handler_Properties.html agrees